# Cannot generate django.po files from docker-compose

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm using Django 3.0.5 inside of a docker-container, linked to an Postgres-container.

I would like to generate django.po files but when I'm trying to use this command:

```sh
docker-compose run web python3 manage.py makemessages -l en
```

I got this error:

> CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.

Meanwhile, when I directly access to my container, it works: (Here, `ad2b13f2fe87` is the ID of my django-container)

```sh
docker exec -it ad2b13f2fe87 bash

root@ad2b13f2fe87:/code# gettext --version
gettext (GNU gettext-runtime) 0.19.8.1
...

root@ad2b13f2fe87:/src# python3 manage.py makemessages -l en
processing locale en
```

Can someone explain me what the issue is?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the issue.

By default, the Python image I use as Django is not updated.

In my Python (Django) `Dockerfile`, I just added:

```
RUN apt update
RUN apt install gettext -y
```

And in my `requirements.txt`, I also added this:

```
# i18n
python-gettext==4.0
```

Now, the command `docker-compose run <python-django-service> python3 manage.py makemessages -l en` works and my `django.po` files are correctly generated.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same problem, whene I tried to install gettext package in my container, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Moci0.png)

To solve this, I added these 2 lines in my DockerFile:

```
RUN apk update
RUN apk add gettext
```

and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).